# Building Lists of File Paths using ToString

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, tostring

I've created a constructor class to call up to build my lists but I'm getting an error:

> error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to`System.Collections.Generic.List'

I'm confused because I thought a file list was a string. What do I need to convert the type to?

```
// Create Constructor Class
public class ImagePath
{
    public string path;

    public ImagePath (string newPath)
    {
        path = newPath;
    }
}

public class LoadGalleryList : MonoBehaviour
{       
    void Start()
    {
        // Call ImagePath Constructor Class to build Lists
        List<ImagePath> arctopithecusImageList = Directory.GetFiles(@"/Users/kenmarold/Screenshots/ARCTOPITHECUS/", "*.jpg").ToList();
        List<ImagePath> arctopithecusPNGImageList = Directory.GetFiles(@"/Users/kenmarold/Screenshots/ARCTOPITHECUS/", "*.jpg").ToList();
        List<ImagePath> gulonImageList = Directory.GetFiles(@"/Users/kenmarold/Screenshots/ARCTOPITHECUS/", "*.jpg").ToList();
        List<ImagePath> scythianWolfImageList = Directory.GetFiles(@"/Users/kenmarold/Screenshots/ARCTOPITHECUS/", "*.jpg").ToList();
        List<ImagePath> simivulpaImageList = Directory.GetFiles(@"/Users/kenmarold/Screenshots/ARCTOPITHECUS/", "*.jpg").ToList();
        List<ImagePath> succorathImageList = Directory.GetFiles(@"/Users/kenmarold/Screenshots/ARCTOPITHECUS/", "*.jpg").ToList();
        List<ImagePath> tatusImageList = Directory.GetFiles(@"/Users/kenmarold/Screenshots/ARCTOPITHECUS/", "*.jpg").ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`GetFiles().ToList()` returns a `List<string>`, which you are trying to store in a `List<ImagePath>` object.  You need to convert each element in the `List<string>` to an `ImagePath`.

LINQ can solve your problem like so:

```
List<ImagePath> imagePathList =
    Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath).Select(f => new ImagePath(f)).ToList();
```